# Having time_zone_select default to system timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

How can I use the `ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper` method `time_zone_select` and have the selected value default to the current (system) timezone?

This works fine:

```
time_zone_select( "user", 
                  "time_zone",
                  nil,
                  :default => "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" )
```

How can I replace `Pacific Time (US & Canada)` with valid code for the current zone?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Time.zone.name](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html), so:

```
time_zone_select(:user, :time_zone, nil, default: Time.zone.name)
```

Comment: `Time.zone.now` returns `UTC` for me, regardless of what the timezone is on my server. `% date` returns the correct timezone `Sat Aug  2 17:08:03 PDT 2014`, as does (ruby) `Time.now`.